# Creation of a short document description for programming languages in a pop-up window like vscode?

Tags: neovim, lsp, popup-menu

How can we have a short summary about documents of programming languages (Python and Javascript is important for me) or frameworks in Neovim? I want to see a short description of APIs and keywords in a popup when I type, like this picture in Vscode.

[image]

I could create my popup like this below picture with `nvim-lspconfig` and `nvim-cmp`.

[image]

Can we create that vscode popup in Neovim?

Comment: Do you know the `K` command. I believe it should provide an approximation of what you want. I would be interested to know what you miss from that command to help you further :-)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt actually I have this : `vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, "n", "K", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.hover()<CR>", opts)` and that picture is come with `K`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my `lsp-server` from `pyright` to `jedi_language_server` and it works now.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look to the following two plugins that could somehow fit the bill:

- [lsp_signature](https://github.com/ray-x/lsp_signature.nvim)
- [goto-preview](https://github.com/rmagatti/goto-preview)

Comment: `lsp_signature` is very good plugin but it gives the same information.